# Reading XML string from a SQL Server database using C#

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I'm storing an XML as a string in a column of a table I have in SQL Server 2008. I'm thinking of using Linq-to-XML to read the string as an `XElement`.

My question is, would using Linq-to-XML make the process of reading the xml from the table column slower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This test found XMLReader to have the best performance: http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/performance_linq_to_sql_vs.html